# How to find missing values in groups

Tags: python, pandas, distinct-values

I have a large dataset of restaurant inspections. One inspection will trigger several code violations. I want to find out if any inspections don't contain a specific code violation (for evidence of pests). I have the data in a Pandas data frame.

I tried separating the data frame based on whether the violation for pests was included. And I tried to group by the violation code. Can't seem to figure it out.

With the pest violation as "3A", data could look like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'visit' : ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3'],
    'violation' : ['3A', '4B', '5C', '3A', '6C', '7D', '8E']
    })
```

```py
  visit violation
0     1        3A
1     1        4B
2     1        5C
3     2        3A
4     2        6C
5     3        7D
6     3        8E
```

I'd like to end up with this:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'visit' : ['3', '3'], 'violation' : ['7D', '8E']
    })
```

```py
Out[15]: 
  visit violation
0     3        7D
1     3        8E
```

Comment: I don't get the logic

Comment: The same "visit" number will appear on several rows with different "violation" codes. Are there any sets in the same "visit" that don't contain the "violation" code for "3A"?

Comment: I answered already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
value = '3A'
print(df.groupby('visit').filter(lambda x: all(value != i for i in x['violation'])))
```

Output:

```
  violation visit
5        7D     3
6        8E     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be:

```py
violation_visits = df[df['violation']=='3A']['visit'].unique()
df[~df['visit'].isin(violation_visits.tolist())]

Out[16]: 
  visit violation
5     3        7D
6     3        8E
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using filter

```
df.groupby('visit').filter(lambda x : ~x['violation'].eq('3A').any())
  visit violation
5     3        7D
6     3        8E
```

Another way using `transform`

```
df[df.violation.ne('3A').groupby(df.visit).transform('all')]
  visit violation
5     3        7D
6     3        8E
```